# A logic circuit is given two 2-bit binary numbers A and Bas its inputs. The circuit consists of two outputs Y1 and Y2

Tags: logic, circuit, truthtable

A logic circuit is given two 2-bit binary numbers A and Bas its inputs. The circuit consists of two outputs Y1 and Y2. The output values of Y1 and Y2 are obtained as follows:
If A<B, then Y1 and Y2 will be equal to A-B. Else Y1 and Y2 will be equal to A.

How To Determinate truth table for this

Answer (score 0):

There are two inputs A[0:1] and B[0:1], 4 inputs in total. Your truth table will have 16 inputs(rows).Are Y1 and Y2 2-bit outputs and is it magnitude of A-B? If yes, The left two columns can be A and next two will be B. For 6 of these rows from 16 cases, A<B in 6 cases ([A,B] = {[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]}). these six rows will have Y1 = Y2 = [B-A]. All other rows will have Y1 = Y1 = A input. Seems straightforward, but I may be missing something here.